# Google charts Column chart, is it possible to hide "count", as shown in screenshot?

Tags: google-visualization

Because of less width i can see that "count" only on onhover mouse. 
How to hide that, plz help me

Comment: don't see a screen shot, please share code / options used to draw the chart -- as a guess, try this option --> `legend: 'none'`

Comment: var options = {
          title: 'Merchant Report',
          vAxis: { 
            format: '#',  
            gridlines: { count: gridcount},
          },
          
          series: { 0: {color: '#12B2CA'},},
         };

Comment: @WhiteHat Thanks a lot for your answer, i used  legend: 'none'. Now count is removed.